# How to deploy a Heroku app that takes longer than 60 seconds to compile?

Tags: heroku, web-deployment

*Problem Compiling before Deploy:*
I'm checking in compiled files to my GitHub repo (which I don't want). I can't use `.gitignore` because any file that's gitignored is also ignored entirely by Heroku. Should I just maintain a separate deploy branch with just the compiled files?

*Problem Compiling after Deploy:*
My compilation takes longer than 60 seconds, and Heroku shuts down the app because of this.

```
heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

What's the best way to deploy a Heroku app that takes longer than 60 seconds to compile? At what point should compilation be initiated? predeploy or post?

My app is compiled down to JavaScript, and then the app is started with `node server.js`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but for this I moved my compilation step to a build hook (heroku-postbuild script in package.json). This doesn't count against the server startup time, then just startup the server on start.